# Azure Startup.cmd unable to bind to localhost

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-roles, startupscript

Out of the box Azure Web Role seems to bind the website to specific IP Address. As a part of deployment, we need to bind the website to listen to localhost or 127.0.0.1.

I've configured my service definition as below:

```
<Startup>
      <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated">
        <Environment>
          <Variable name="ComputeEmulatorRunning">
            <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
          </Variable>
        </Environment>
      </Task>
    </Startup>
```

On Starup.cmd file I've line below:

> eventcreate /ID 1 /L APPLICATION /T INFORMATION /SO AzureRoleStartup
>   /D "Executing: BindIISSite.ps1" powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy
>   unrestricted -Command ".\BindIISSite.ps1"

On BinIISite.ps1 I've PS script below:

```
import-module WebAdministration
New-WebBinding -Name "*MyWebsite*" -IPAddress "*" -Port 8089
```

With all setting above, I noticed that "MyWebSite" is not bound to * for port 8089.

But when I run the startup.cmd manually in Azure VM, it seems to bind correctly. Any idea what may be wrong above?

Answer (score 0):

The `New-WebBinding` cmdlet parameter `Name` does not accept wildcard characters, so in your script, it is looking for a site with the literal name `*MyWebSite*`, and that could cause the binding to fail.

Comment: Interesting, why does it work when I RDP to VM and manually run startup.cmd.

Comment: I think we are missing some information. What are the exact circumstances when the script does not work? Are you attempting to run this command from a workstation against resources on the VM?

Comment: From startup script as part of azure deploy

Comment: I am not really familiar with azure. My last idea would be that maybe, the website does not exist at the time the script is run during the azure deploy